# C# IO Отказано в доступе по пути "pack-*.idx"

Tags: c#, io

В конце программы пытаюсь удалить ранее созданную директорию temp

```
string tempDir = @"\folder\temp";

///Множество операций внутри temp///
Directory.Delete(tempDir, true);
```

в итоге Delete() выдает `UnauthorizedAccessException Отказано в доступе по пути "pack-*.idx".`

в программе настроен манифест на запуск под админом, рабочая директория лежит на диске L:\ однако удаление не удается

Comment: Удаляйте файлы рекурсивно. Наверняка какие-то из них используются и не могут быть удалены.

Comment: ну флаг на рекурсивное удаление и так стоит, но я полагаю вы о том, чтобы пустить цикл по папке и удалять каждый файл индивидуально?

Comment: да, это помогло понять в чем ошибка, хотя я мог бы и раньше открыть temp, там осталась директория .git которая цепляется за жизнь